# ASP.NET: accessdb odbc - when getting an exception, how can i see the full stack trace?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, exception, odbc

Using ASP.NET as programming language on IIS Server.
the Database is access and i connect to the database using ODBC.

when i fill some form in the website and press submit i get an exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query.
```

and stack trace is:

```
  site.modGlobal.ExecuteSQL(String sqlStr, OdbcConnection& dbcon) +128
  site.orderprd.imgbtnNextOrder_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) +3951
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +86
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +115
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent      (String eventArgument) +7
  System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +11
  System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +33
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1746
```

this is not a website that i wrote so i cannot guess where the query was executed.
how can i get a more complete stack trace in order to pinpoint the location this command was executed ?

Comment: It looks like the query was executed in `site.modGlobal.ExecuteSQL` which was called by `site.orderprd.imgbtnNextOrder_Click` which was called in response to an `ImageButton` being clicked.  What more is needed?

Comment: +1 to david. Error seems to be indicating error to be from this ExecuteSQL method of modGlobal class i.e modGlobal.ExecuteSQL(String sqlStr, OdbcConnection& dbcon) - could it be that this method is directly calling the database to execute the SQL and hence it is the deepest link in the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace seems quite explicit:

```
site.modGlobal.ExecuteSQL(String sqlStr, OdbcConnection& dbcon) +128
site.orderprd.imgbtnNextOrder_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) +3951
```

Those lines should give you all the information you need.